# How to hide emoji in default after lollipop?

Tags: android, keyboard, emoji

This code Only used to disable emoji but I want to hide emoji from default Android keypad after lollipop. here is my code.

http://i.prntscr.com/cfc49963d6fe4a5bbf4b4a8ead97d96a.png

register.xml:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/mail_compose_content_text"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/mail_compose_subject_text"
    android:layout_margin="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/border_gray"
    android:cursorVisible="true"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:hint="Message"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textColorHint="#a9a9a9"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
    android:textSize="15sp" />
```

Java file:

```
mail_compose_content_text.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{EMOJI_FILTER});

public static InputFilter EMOJI_FILTER = new InputFilter() {

    @Override
    public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end, Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {
        for (int index = start; index < end; index++) {

            int type = Character.getType(source.charAt(index));

            if (type == Character.SURROGATE) {
                return "";
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
};
```